# Count date in same day as 0

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I'm try to write Oracle SQL function. Currently i try to get number of working day with cut-off point at 4.30. In problem is, how can i get the number of working day in same day as 0.

Example :

> Staff opened request at 9.30 AM
>
> Staff close the request at 4.15 (which is before cut off time)

So, the number of working day for example above should be 0 because it before cut-off time.

Comment: instead of cut-off point use minimum working hours per a day. You can get working hours of a employee per day with the use of  (close request time-open request time).

Comment: Post some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the current day at 16.30 as a reference date and then calculate the difference between that date and the request date:

```
SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-RRRR') || ' 16:30','DD-MM-RRRR HH24:MI') - TO_DATE('09-12-2015 09:30','DD-MM-RRRR HH24:MI')) days 
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Can be simplified to `SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE(  '16:30','HH24:MI') - TO_DATE('09:30','HH24:MI')) days 
FROM DUAL;`

Comment: what if we wanted to check different days?